# How to auto-generate the *-javadoc.jar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

I created the javadocs in my Eclipse Project with the *Export >> Java >> Java-doc*. The directory structure is *MyProject >> docs >> javadoc*.
I have two questions:

1. How can I generate the javadoc automactilly with the Eclipse Build?
2. How can I generate the javadoc automactilly with pattner MyProject-javadoc.jar  with Eclipse Build?

The second question is the more important, because I know how generate manually the javadoc, but I don't know how to create the *-javadoc.jar.

Answer (score 7):

When you configure Javadoc generation using wizard invoked from `Project->Generate Javadoc...` you have an option to generate `ant` script for your settings. You can then invoke (or copy to) the generated ant target from your main build script.

To generate the archive itself you can simply package the folder with generated documentation as a jar file. Add something similar to the following target to your ant scripts:

```
<target depends="javadoc" description="build javadoc jar" name="package-docs">
    <jar compress="true" destfile="javadoc.jar" basedir="doc" />
</target>
```

Comment: Has this changed in Eclipse Kepler? Can't seem to find the option to generate the ant script when using Project -> Generate Javadoc...  Maybe I'm missing it somewhere.

Comment: @lnunno it is still there. It is in the third screen of `Javadoc Generation` wizard, so you have to click `Next` twice to get there. The option is called `Save the settings of this Javadoc export as an Ant script`.